# How to check if Each value in $array1 the present in $array2 or not

Tags: php, arrays

I have known the cause of the problem, not in the code.
Content of the field at the base value of each line separately
So used `str_replace` to delete the line

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array1 = str_replace("\n","",$array1);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);
$array2 = str_replace("\n","",$array2);

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    if (in_array($value,$array2))
    {
        //true
    }else{
        //false
    }
}
```

---

I have a problem when I check `if Each value in $array2 is present in $array1 or not`

Table data:

```
filed1               | filed2
ahmed,jon,maya,omar  | omar,maya
```

My code:

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);

        $length = count($array1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            if (in_array($array1[$i] , $array2))
            {
                //true
            }else{
                //false
            }
        }
```

or this:

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    if (in_array($value,$array2))
    {
        //true
    }else{
        //false
    }
}
```

My problem is my code doesn't work good, I am sure that my query gives the results and arrays too.

Output of array1:

```
Array ( [0] => maya [1] => omar [2] => ahmed [3] => join)
```

Output of array2:

```
Array ( [0] => omar [1] => maya )
```

So, where is the error in my code?!

Note :

I don't want `check all value from array2 are in array1`, I want `check if Each value in $array2 is present in $array1 or not` - focus on this word `Each value` not `all value`

Like:

```
if (in_array('omar',$array1))
{
    echo 'found';
}else{
    echo 'not found'; }
    if (in_array('maya',$array1))
    {
        echo 'found';
    }else{
        echo 'not found';
    } 
    if (in_array('jon',$array1))
    { 
        echo 'found';
    }else{
        echo 'not found';
    }
etc ...
```

But I do not want it this way, I want it inside a loop.

Comment: Your code looks fine! (Both versions!) So check that your arrays have content again and make sure there are no errors in your code somewhere.

Comment: @Billy yeah iam sure about arrays results , i put it Above , and Do not show any errors

Comment: I don't mean check for errors being output I mean there must be an error (as in, not what you want, even if the code still runs) in your code. It might be worth stepping through your code with a debugging tool such as XDebug

Comment: Shouldn't $query[filed1] be $query['filed1']?

Comment: @adamp although OP is claiming that the arrays are being populated by those lines, that does seem to be an error.

Comment: thnx .. I have known the cause of the problem, not in my code , Placed above the solution

Comment: You have said that four times, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have known the cause of the problem, not in the code ... 
Content of the field at the base value of each line separately
So used `str_replace` to delete the line

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query[filed1]);
$array1 = str_replace("\n","",$array1);
$array2 = explode(",",$query[filed2]);
$array2 = str_replace("\n","",$array2);

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    if (in_array($value,$array2))
    {
        //true
    }else{
        //false
    }
}
```

Comment: hello omar, actually thats what i was thinking, the original content may have had newlines, whitspaces, etc, thats why in my revision, i used `trim` on each arrays, so its assured that every comparison inside the loop will be processed correctly, anyway its good you found your way

Comment: @Ghost - thnx brother - but if `trim` delete `whitspaces` will not get original content , becouse here on data i put only first name , if i put a value like this `omar adam,ghost rider,omar dealo,elc..` on array will be `omaradam,ghostrider,omardealo,elc..`

Comment: oh okay, anyway, im glad it worked out on your part, by the way, just an advice, is something happened and some part didn't work you can also try out `strpos` to search

Comment: @Ghost thnx brother for your help

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a loop in this case if you really want to, a simple foreach should suffice:

```
$array1 = array_map('trim', $array1); // on explode make sure remove trailing/leading spaces
$array2 = array_map('trim', $array2);

foreach($array1 as $name) { // so each value of array1
    if(in_array($name, $array2)) { // is compared inside the contents of array2
        // if found
        echo "$name is found in " . '$array2';
    } else {
        echo "$name is NOT found in " . '$array2';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ghost yeah not work , i try it already , look in my code .. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be iterating over array2 so all values of array2 are checked, not the other way around, because you said: "

> check if Each value in $array2...

```
$query = $db->query_first("SELECT * FROM table ");
$array1 = explode(",",$query['filed1']);
$array2 = explode(",",$query['filed2']);

foreach($array2 as $value)
{
    if (in_array($value,$array1))
    {
        //true
    }else{
        //false
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx .. I have known the cause of the problem, not in my code , Placed above the solution

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff()` is a single function approach to getting an array of items not present in further arrays

```
$array1 = array('ahmed','jon','maya','omar');
$array2 = array('omar','maya');
$result = array_diff($array1,$array2); // Array ( [0] => ahmed [1] => jon )
```

you may need to switch parameter order to achieve your desired outcome.

you can also use `array_intersect()` to perform the reverse

Comment: thnx .. I have known the cause of the problem, not in my code , Placed above the solution

Answer (score 0):

@Ghost's solution produced the correct output, but as you state, you know the problem isn't your code. Apparently the problem is that the format of the data you are querying isn't quite matching. So, here is how you can approach debugging this problem:

## var_dump() the data

The likely suspect is that some of the data have padding. (It's odd that @Ghost's suggestion of trimming the results didn't work.)

```
    $array1 = explode(",",$query['filed1']);
    $array2 = explode(",",$query['filed2']);
    var_dump($array1);
    echo "\n";
    var_dump($array2);
    echo "\n";
```

## Inspect comparisons in the iteration

The above should reveal the problem. If not, you could take it a step deeper and see which exact comparison is failing in the in_array. If you don't have xdebug available, just loop within the loop:

```
    foreach ($array1 as $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $array2)) {
            echo "\n[$value found in \$array2]\n";
        } else {
            echo "\n[$value NOT found in \$array2]\n";
        }

        foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
            if ($value !== $value2) {
                echo "\$array1's '$value' !== \$array2's '$value2'\n";
            } else {
                echo "\$array1's '$value' === \$array2's '$value2'\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

The output will show you exactly what is wrong.

*Note*: You should include filed1 and filed2 in quotes since you are using them as string keys. When PHP parses your code, it will emit a notice (error) and fall back on interpreting it as a string.

Comment: thnx .. I have known the cause of the problem, not in my code , Placed above the solution